# Django query to filter out current user from a list of users

Tags: django

I have a query that returns a list of users. It contains the current logged in user and I would like to make the same query without returning this user. In my models Book has a foreignkey to Library called library and Library has a m2m to users called subscribers. It's probably not important as a simple query to all users should probably work for the example as well.

```
users = book.library.subscribers.all()
```

request.user ends up in users too and I don't want that. I know I could take it out of the list after making the query but I would like to know if there is directly a way to exclude request.user from the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
book.library.subscribers.exclude(user=request.user)
```

Assuming, user is the attribute that stores the users

Comment: I'm not sure to understand where does 'user' come from? The attribute that stores the users in Library is 'subscribers' (m2m to User). And in Book there is no attribute that stores the users.

Comment: ok..In the models, what is `subscribers defined as`? If what you are describing is true, you are bound to get an error

Comment: subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='subscribers')